# qTranslate save last opened language editing tab?

Tags: wordpress, editor, tinymce, multilingual, qtranslate

I think I have a common problem here:

I am using Wordpress 3.4.1 and qTranslate 2.5.31. Currently I have 2 Languages activated.

My problem is as follows:

When I edit my second language (either Visual or in HTML), and I save the Page/Post, then the editor jumps back to my default language when saved.

Is there a possibility to save the current language editor state after saving the Post/Page ?

It is pretty annoying ...

Comment: It is also annoying people spent time and effort answering questions of yours and none is accepted so far.

Comment: ...i will even refuse to read the question content